# Container Managed Persistence and Stored procs that create temporary tables

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc, websphere

I'm working with some legacy JDBC code, and configuring it to use Container Managed Persistence, and so far it's worked fine with transactions managed for me, except it fails on stored procedure calls.

Some of the stored procedures create temporary tables, which require a commit in the middle of the transaction.  So I get an exception complaining that I can't call commit if I'm using Container managed persistence.

Does anyone know a way around this?

More Info:

If I add a commit() to the end of my queries, I get:

**DSRA9350E: Operation Connection.commit is not allowed during a global transaction.**

So I presumed that the Sybase JDBC 4 XA driver is managing transactions for me.  It rolls back if I throw an exception in my code.

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    if ( connection == null ) {
        this.connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        this.connection.setAutoCommit(!useTransaction);
        this.connection.setTransactionIsolation(transactionIsolationLevel);
    }
    logger.info("Connection  [ "+ connection.toString() +" ]");
    return connection;
}
```

The part where I get the connection typically has autocommit as 'false', whereas for stored procs, it has autocommit as 'true'.  But either way, stored procs with temp tables get:

**java.sql.SQLException: SELECT INTO command not allowed within multi-statement transaction.**

It is a bit confusing.  The data sources are set up by the container, and I just get them from the context using resource-ref tags.  They are XA datasources, so they provide a global transaction.  I try to disable it with Spring:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package.path.to.class.with.method" />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" />
```

by providing 
@Component on the class and @Transactional on the method

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public ResultSet executeProcedure(String sql, String[] parameterTypes, 
        String[] parameterValues) throws SEEException {

    SqlParameters parameters = this.convertParameters(parameterTypes, parameterValues);
    return super.executeProdedure(sql, parameters);
}
```

But I still get the error.

The stored proc looks a bit like this, (the procxmode is UNCHAINED).  The stored proc defn is a transaction itself, so I presume I must have no active transaction going in.  But I won't be able to edit the stored proc itself.  It's been in production for years:

```
define sp_example
begin
   create table #temp {}
   begin
      insert into #temp {}
   end
   begin
      select from #temp {}
   end
end
```

Comment: Please add more details: Show both the Java code with CMP/CMT that calls the stored procedure, and the stored procedure which creates a temporary table. Which database?

Comment: I've added some more info to the question

Comment: have you tried to pull the code for stored procedure into another method and exclude it from the transaction using notsupported transaction type?http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html

Comment: Hi Raji, yes, I've tried with NotSupported... no luck.  I've added more info to show what I've done.  Perhaps Spring isn't finding the annotation for some reason, but I have no idea yet.

Answer (score 1):

The term container-managed persistence in ejb 2.x means that the EJB container handles all database access required by the entity bean, the scope is defined by a method implementation. If you need to control transaction such as calling commit inside a method execution you will be forced to use Bean managed persistence and the UserTransaction interface methods to control it.

Unfortunately the ejb 2.x specs does not allow you to have a mixed CMP/BMP entity bean, you need to choose one that fits your business case.

Comment: I don't mind using BMP if that's an option... but the datasources are configured in WAS as XA, so I'm getting a global transaction by default.  What I probably need is transaction suspension, but it's not working.  This link seems to be about my problem: http://lwpro2.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/sybase-sp-set-chained-off/ but I've already tried setAutoCommit(true) and setAutoCommit(false).

Comment: Do you know a way to disable XA temporarily?  Presumably the reason why my code isn't working is because @Transactional isn't in an EJB?

Comment: I don't think you can disable XA if you're using a XA driver configuratino. You might not use it at all but I don't think you can disable it during a transaction.

Comment: Also about the setAutoCommit, this is valid only if you're using JDBC directly I don't think you can do it in a CMP